# Can we arbitrarily add or remove single points from computations involving a continuous random variable?

Tags: random-variables

Say I have a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ and some real-valued random variable $X$ such that the distribution of $X$ is continuous.

Say $\Sigma_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the typical Borel algebra on the reals. Is it always the case that for any non-empty $\sigma \in \Sigma_{\mathbb{R}}$ and for any $b \in \sigma$, we have that:

\begin{align*}
    \mu(\omega\ |\ X(\omega) \in \sigma) = \\
    \int_{a \in \sigma} \mu(\omega\ |\ X(\omega) \in da) = \\
    \mu(\omega\ |\ X(\omega) \in \left[\sigma - \{b\}\right]) = \\
    \int_{a \in \left[\sigma - \{b\}\right]} \mu(\omega\ |\ X(\omega) \in da)
\end{align*}

If this is not the case for all continuous distributions, does this hold if we assume that the distribution of $X$ is Gaussian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  For $X$ to be continuous *means* that $P(X=b)=0$ for each $b\in\mathbb R$.  The difference between your $P(X\in S)$ and your $P(X\in S\setminus \{ b\})$ is exactly $P(X\in\{b\})=P(X=b)$, which is by assumption zero.